# Proper json responses when using passport.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, authentication

I'm using Passport.js for authentication in an Express 4 API. Mostly everything works fine but I'm finding that sending proper json responses i.e error messages or objects is difficult with passport. For example this is my `LocalStrategy` for loggin in:

```
  passport.use (
    'login',
    new LocalStrategy (
      {
        usernameField: 'email',
      },
      (email, password, done) => {
        User.findOne ({email: email}, (err, foundUser) => {
          if (err) return done (err);

          if (!foundUser) {
            return done (null, false, {
              message: 'Invalid Username.',
            });
          }

          if (!foundUser.comparePassword (password)) {
            return done (null, false, {
              message: 'Invalid Password.',
            });
          }

          return done (null, foundUser);
        });
      }
    )
  );
```

I'm setting custom `message`s for when the authentication fails, but these messages never show up in my api responses. How do I send messages like these if something goes wrong during authentication?

```
app.post (
  '/signup',
  passport.authenticate ('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/user',
    failureMessage: true,
    successMessage: true,
  })
);
```

Moreover, Instead setting redirects like `successRedirect` I want to send proper json responses for each case and if an error occurs I want to send that as a json object instead of redirecting to a route. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `async await` here.

```
passport.use(
  'login',
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        // now if user exists it will give the whole document if not then null, now you can test your conditions based on this user flag /
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

for the last case you mentioned, you can send the response as

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('login'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Your message here',
    user: req.user,
  });
});
```

here it should be login in `passport.authenticate('login')` as you are using local strategy by using login in above code.

Comment: This is not I want. What I'm asking is how do I send the `message` objects that I pass in the done method like: `          if (!foundUser) {
            return done (null, false, {
              message: 'Invalid Username.',
            });
          }` to the client as json responses in case authentication fails somewhere.